# How to iterate over each pair of items in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I'm making a gravity simulator and I need to calculate the resultant force acting upon each body.

In order to do this, I need to iterate through every pair of bodies in a dictionary `(id: instance of Body class)` and get the gravitational force between those two bodies. Then, I would add up all the forces and get the resultants.

But, how do I iterate over each pair of items in a dictionary only once in Python? If the celestial bodies were kept in a list, it would be simple:

```
for i in range(len(bodies)):
    for j in range(len(bodies) - i - 1):
        k = j - i + 1
        b1 = bodies[i]
        b2 = bodies[k]
```

Comment: note: if you want to support large number of bodies; you could use [`O(n * log n)` algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation#Calculation_optimizations) instead of `O(n * n)`. See discussion in "Programming Pearls" book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`values()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and `itertools`' [`combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) are ideal for this use case.

```
from itertools import combinations
for a, b in combinations(bodies.values(), 2):
    print a, b
```

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for `itertools.combinations()`:

An example:

```
In [76]: lis=['a','b','c','d']  #consider these as your dictionary items

In [77]: [x for x in combinations(lis,2)]
Out[77]: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) module provides an excellent `combinations` method you could use:

```
from itertools import combinations

bodies = {}
# add bodies

for a,b in combinations(bodies.values(), 2):
    # a and b are a pair of bodies. do stuff
    pass
```

Incidentally, this will still work even if you use a list:

```
from itertools import combinations

bodies = []
# add bodies

for a,b in combinations(bodies, 2):
    pass
```